# How to iterate for specific elements in a list?

Tags: python, list

Say I have a large list of tuples, 'a' given as follows:

`a = [(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), (10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,18,19), (20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28) ..... ]`

For such a list, how do I make another list by iteration and combine the corresponding elements to get the following:

`a = [(0, 10, 20...), (1, 11, 21)....]`

Also, lets say I have another list of Arrays,

`b = [A, B, C, D, E, F, G ,H, I]`

So, how would I combine a and b to make another list c such that:

`c = [A(0,10,20), B(1,11,21) ....]`

Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like two different questions. Have you tried to solve them and run into problems? What are those problems?

Comment: What do you mean by Arrays? That's not the correct syntax for indexing arrays in Python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first `a` list looks like it's been [zipped](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip). You need to unzip it.
Like so -

```
>>> a = [(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), (10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,18,19), (20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28)]
>>> zip(*a)
[(0, 10, 20), (1, 11, 21), (2, 12, 22), (3, 13, 23), (4, 14, 24), (5, 15, 25), (6, 16, 26), (7, 17, 27), (8, 18, 28)]
```

For the second problem, it seem to be the inverse of the first (Assuming that `b` has 'ABC' as characters).So zip them -

```
>>> a = zip(*a)
>>> b = "ABCDEFGHI"
>>> zip(b,a)
[('A', (0, 10, 20)), ('B', (1, 11, 21)), ('C', (2, 12, 22)), ('D', (3, 13, 23)), ('E', (4, 14, 24)), ('F', (5, 15, 25)), ('G', (6, 16, 26)), ('H', (7, 17, 27)), ('I', (8, 18, 28))]
```

**EDIT**
As suggested by gnibbler in the comments, this method involves upacking of the parameters - (Assuming `b` as a complex List)

```
>>> b = [[65, 66], [67, 68], [69, 70], [71, 72], [73, 74], [75, 76], [77, 78], [79, 80], [81, 82]]
>>> zip(b, *a)
[([65, 66], 0, 10, 20), ([67, 68], 1, 11, 21), ([69, 70], 2, 12, 22), ([71, 72], 3, 13, 23), ([73, 74], 4, 14, 24), ([75, 76], 5, 15, 25), ([77, 78], 6, 16, 26), ([79, 80], 7, 17, 27), ([81, 82], 8, 18, 28)]
```

For more clarity over the difference, here is the example with my earlier answer -

```
>>> zip(b, zip(*a))
[([65, 66], (0, 10, 20)), ([67, 68], (1, 11, 21)), ([69, 70], (2, 12, 22)), ([71, 72], (3, 13, 23)), ([73, 74], (4, 14, 24)), ([75, 76], (5, 15, 25)), ([77, 78], (6, 16, 26)), ([79, 80], (7, 17, 27)), ([81, 82], (8, 18, 28))]
```

Comment: For the second part, just use the original `a`. `zip(b, *a)` Extract the Array+index in a list comprehension

Comment: I tried it and I got the Arrays in the wrong order for some reason. Any thoughts on why that might be?

Comment: @gnibbler True, but unpacking `a` gives a slightly different output than what I've shown. Something like this - `('A', 0, 10, 20),...` instead of `('A', (0, 10, 20)),`(which is what I assumed). Probably it's for the OP to decide.

Comment: @Pythonaddict hmm... maybe you can try reversing the parameters in `zip()`

Comment: @Kamehameha, yes, but the letters are supposed to represent arrays. Python3 has a nice syntax to unpack the resultant tuples to array, index. `[arr[idx] for arr, *idx in zip(b, *a)]`

Comment: @gnibbler yeah I read the question again, and added yours in the edit, but given the question, I feel both are right :)